# Can Linux users sniff 'n watch which torrents I am downloading on my Macintosh?

Tags: linux, macos, bittorrent

I'm using **uTorrent client** to download some games and files on my work.

I am using Mac OS X 10.5. Other employees use Linux.

Can they watch my files or see what I am downloading?

I tried to use Packet Peeper and I saw encrypted data nothing to read. I need to know if I am safe or anyone can see the name of the files I'm downloading.

Comment: I hope for you that this isn't illegal, because you'd risk your job.

Comment: If you are on a company workstation and/or network, you **are not safe**. Any sysadmin worth his salt will detect network abuse even through VPN services, and may investigate your stuff after you leave. Torrent at your own risk.

Answer (score 1):

If they use a packet sniffer, they can see that you are using a torrent client. A more powerful sniffer like WireShark can reassamble the BitTorrent packets to see the conversation. See [documentation here](http://wiki.wireshark.org/BitTorrent).

Comment: mmm this mean it need advanced software and advanced employee to know that ok thanks so much

Comment: or use an private VPN service.

Comment: Or don't do it at all.

Comment: "this mean it need advanced software and advanced employee to know that" - Security through obscurity is still better than safety through assumed idiocy/incompetence.